# Minimum cost to connect some cabins

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

A big government organisation set up an office in Bangalore. The office was build up in a rectangular shape, so all of its floors are also in the
rectangular shape. The dimension of the office is X units x Y units. Each Floor of the office is having large sitting capacity for its employees. All the
cabins of the employees are in square form. So the area of each floor is divided in X*Y cabins of dimension 1 unit x 1 unit.

See the diagram given the example.

[image]

Here in the above image,

P means that employees can pass their files to each other

NP means that employees can't pass their files to each other

As shown in the above example floor size is 4 unit x 5 unit and there are 4*5=20 cabins on the floor, 1 unit x 1 unit cabins. Some of the cabins have well
attached to each other and some are not. The Cabins which are well attached to each other, passing of files in these cabins is very easy. Other cabins
which are not well attached to each other, passing of files in these cabins are not possible. Cabins are shown in the above figure with P and NP labels
respectively.

So cabin at (3, 1) can pass files at (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2) and (4, 2). These all attached part cumulatively forms a full passing region. Hence, the whole floor is divided in various P- regions due to No Passing cabins.

Like in above example, we have two P- regions one in left and one in right. Organisation can correct the cabin positions in NP-regions but it would
cause some cost and every NP cabin may have the different cost. In fact, there is no use of correcting NP cabins because their work is very different.
Organisation concern is to connect the various P regions. This is possible if some of the NP cabins are converted into P cabins. So the challenging task
for the organisation is that it wants to organize these cabins in least possible cost.

[image]

Left figure represents the cabins situation whether it is P or NP. Right Figure is having some value written in each cabin and it is the cost required to
organize the cabins in the floor. As shown in the figure that every P cabin has -1 cost it means no cost is required to organize these cabins. But for
every NP cabin there is some positive cost associated. There are four P regions in this example, all the P-regions consist of only 1 cabin. The challenge
for the organisation is to connect all the four P-regions (that too in the least possible cost).

This can be done in the various ways; two possible ways are as follows-

[image]

Cost for method 1 is 10+10+10=30

Cost for method 2 is only 2

So if we organize the NP cabins with cost 2, it would connect all the four different P cabins. And for the above example it is the least possible cost.
You have to return the minimum possible cost in which all the P cabins can be attached to each other.

Output Specifications:

It is an integer which specifies the minimum possible cost in which all the P cabins can be attached to each other

or

return 0 if all the P cabins already attached to each other or if there are no P cabins

My Code:-

```
class Code {
    public int[][] array;

    boolean flag=true;
    int[][] a;
    int R;
    int C;
    int MAX=2147483647;
    LinkedList l=new LinkedList();


    void initialize() {
        R=array.length;
        C=array[0].length;
        a=new int[R][C];

        for(int i=0;i<R && flag;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<C && flag;j++) {
                if(array[i][j]==-1) {
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void process() {
        int p=0,q=0;
        for(int i=R-1;i>=0;i--) {
            for(int j=C-1;j>=0;j--){
                if(array[i][j]==-1) {
                    p=i;
                    q=j;
                    array[i][j]=0;
                }
                a[i][j]=MAX;
            }
        }
        l.add(p);
        l.add(q);
        a[p][q]=0;
    }

    void solve() {
        int p=0,q=0;
        while(l.size()>0) {
            p=(int)l.removeFirst();
            q=(int)l.removeFirst();

            for(int i=p-1;i<=p+1;i++) {
                for(int j=q-1;j<=q+1;j++){
                    if(i>=0 && j>=0 && i<R && j<C && a[i][j]>a[p][q]+array[i][j]) {
                        a[i][j]=a[p][q]+array[i][j];
                        l.add(i);
                        l.add(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int minimumcost() {
        initialize();

        if(flag)
            return 0;

        process();
        solve();

        MAX=0;
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<C;j++){
                if(array[i][j]==0 && a[i][j]>MAX)
                    MAX=a[i][j];
            }
        }

        return MAX;
    }
}
```

Here, array is the array given and minimumcost is the function that returns the answer. Out of 10 test cases, 5 were correct. I am not able to find the mistake.

In my code I first checked if there was atleast one cabin with P. From any one P P I have traversed in all directions (all neighbours) using a linked list (used as a queue here) keeping track of minimum to reach this cell. In the end I have found maximum value.

Comment: So why is this Q getting negative ratings, but no one cares to comment on it? Help this guy understand what he's doing wrong ;-)

Comment: Is your ENTIRE homework assignment really necessary for us to understand a problem with your code? Props to you for actually posting some code but this question is lazily put together. You need to have some consideration for the people actually reading this and put more effort into simplifying what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tnw This is not a homework question. This was asked in a test for a company recruitment. This question was more detailed than it is right now but I have removed whatever part I could remove to cut it short. This much details in question was necessary for proper understanding. And for my code, it is mostly not so confusing if one tries to read though I have added my approach now in the end of text.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Even I thought MST at first but wasnt able to fully apply it here. So I went with a sort of BFS here and not able to see what test case might go wrong.

Comment: @JayC667 Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a Dijkstra-like approach:

Create a union-find data structure with entries for each P-cell and a list of all NP-cells. Merge the entries for neighboring P-cells and sort the NP-cells by their cost. Together with the cost paid so far, this is the description of any state. Put that initial state on an ordered list (ordered by the cost paid so far). Check the union-find if it contains only one connected component. If so, you're done.

If not, proceed as follows: Take the state with the least cost from the list. Choose the NP-cell with the least cost and remove it from the list. Add this state to the state list. Create a copy of this state and add an entry for the chosen cell in the union-find structure and merge it with every neighboring P-cell (the cells that already exist in the union-find structure). Update the cost of the state and insert it into the ordered list. Continue until you have only one connected component left in the union-find structure.

This is basically finding the shortest path in the state graph. This graph may be exponentially large, but you don't have to compute the entire one. As an optimization, you can check if any new state you want to insert into the list is already present (e.g. by using a hash set).

Answer (score 3):

```
public class CandidateCode 
{ 

  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
    System.out.println(minimumpossiblecost("-1@10@-1#10@2@10#-1@10@-1"));
  }
  public static int minimumpossiblecost(String input1)
  {
    String arr[]=input1.split("#");
    int c=arr[0].split("@").length;
    int r=arr.length;
    int intarr[][]= new int[r][];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        intarr[i]= new int[c];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        String row[]=arr[i].split("@");
        for(int j=0;j<row.length;j++)
        {
            intarr[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(row[j]);
        }
    }
    int temp=0;
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<r;j++) 
        {

            temp=0;
            if(intarr[i][j]==-1)
           {
            if(i==0 && j==0)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i+1][j+1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j+1])
                    intarr[i+1][j+1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;


            }
            else if(i==0 && j>0 && j<c-1)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i+1][j-1],intarr[i+1][j+1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j-1])
                    intarr[i+1][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j+1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
            else if(i==0 && j==c-1)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i+1][j-1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j-1])
                    intarr[i+1][j-1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
            else if(i>0 && i<r-1 && j==0)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i-1][j+1],intarr[i+1][j+1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j+1])
                    intarr[i-1][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j+1])
                    intarr[i+1][j+1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
            else if(i>0 && i<r-1 && j==c-1)
            {

            temp=minDiff(intarr[i][j],intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i-1][j-1],intarr[i+1][j-1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i][j])
                    intarr[i][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j-1])
                    intarr[i-1][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j-1])
                    intarr[i+1][j-1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
            else if(i==r-1 && j==0)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i-1][j+1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j+1])
                    intarr[i-1][j+1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;
            }
            else if(i==r-1 && j>0 && j<c-1)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i-1][j-1],intarr[i-1][j+1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j-1])
                    intarr[i-1][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j+1])
                    intarr[i-1][j+1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;
            }
            else if(i==r-1 && j==c-1)
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i-1][j-1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j-1])
                    intarr[i-1][j-1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
            else
            {
                temp=minDiff(intarr[i+1][j],intarr[i-1][j],intarr[i][j+1],intarr[i][j-1],intarr[i-1][j+1],intarr[i-1][j-1],intarr[i+1][j+1],intarr[i+1][j-1]);
                if(temp==intarr[i+1][j])
                    intarr[i+1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j])
                    intarr[i-1][j]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j+1])
                    intarr[i][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i][j-1])
                    intarr[i][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j+1])
                    intarr[i-1][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i-1][j-1])
                    intarr[i-1][j-1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j+1])
                    intarr[i+1][j+1]=-1;
                else if(temp==intarr[i+1][j-1])
                    intarr[i+1][j-1]=-1;
                ans=ans+temp;

            }
         }
        }

    }
    return ans;
  }
  static int minDiff(int ...x)
  {
    int flag=0,min=10000;
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        if(x[i]==-1)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(flag==1)
    return 0;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            if(x[i]<min)
            {
                min=x[i];
            }

        }   
    }
    return min;
  }
}
```